# Read And Validate Data via JSON on MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have program with c# &mvc managing employees time at work. I am trying to do this methods of reading data from JSON to validate the reports data( I have local DB)

```
  public bool ReadAndValidateData(int employeeIdForNewReports, string jsonData, out List<Report> reportsInGrid, out string errorMsg)
        {
 bool result = true;                 

      result = ParseAndCheckBasicData(employeeIdForNewReports, jsonData, out reportsInGrid, out errorMsg);


      if (result)
      {
        result = CheckRules(reportsInGrid, out errorMsg);
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Save Reports method:

```
public string SaveReports(int employeeId, string jsonData)
{
  List<Report> reportListInGrid;
  string errorMsg;
  if (ReadAndValidateData(employeeId, jsonData, out reportListInGrid, out errorMsg))
  {
    SaveChanges(reportListInGrid);

    return "";
  }

  return errorMsg;
}
```

How should I do it? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya not reading json and validate reports fields

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: That does not explain anything. There is no code you shared which does reading of json and validation. `ReadAndValidateData` method is only calling two other methods `ParseAndCheckBasicData` and `CheckRules`. So basically there is no logic in the code you shared. We can't say what's wrong with the code. You also need to share the sample json data and also tell what output do you expect and what exact output you are getting. Did you debug your code and try to find the issue?